# Countdown Timer in Minutes

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program to display a countdown timer which shows minutes and seconds.  I know how to do it in seconds but I'm not sure how I can get it to countdown in minutes and seconds.

For Example the countdown should look like this:

> 2 minutes, 59 seconds
>   2 minutes, 58 seconds
>   2 minutes, 57 seconds
>   etc etc

Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much time (In Minutes) ?");
        int timet= scan.nextInt();
        long delay = timet * 1000;

        do
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(timet / 1);
        timet = timet - 1;
            delay = delay - 1000;

        }
        while (delay != 0);
        System.out.println("Time's Up!");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 60 seconds in a minute. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to multiply timet by 60 to convert minutes to seconds (updated below). You can use modulo (%) to get the seconds remaining. See the 3 lines I added within your "do" to print the time in minutes and seconds as you have described. I did not critique the rest of the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How much time (In Minutes) ?");
    int timet= scan.nextInt() * 60; // Convert to seconds
    long delay = timet * 1000;

    do
    {
      int minutes = timet / 60;
      int seconds = timet % 60;
      System.out.println(minutes +" minute(s), " + seconds + " second(s)");
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      timet = timet - 1;
      delay = delay - 1000;

    }
    while (delay != 0);
    System.out.println("Time's Up!");
  }
}
```

Example Output:

```
How much time (In Minutes) ?
5
5 minute(s), 0 second(s)
4 minute(s), 59 second(s)
4 minute(s), 58 second(s)
4 minute(s), 57 second(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you should begin by thinking how you could format just seconds (I would use something like),

```
private static String formatSeconds(long seconds) {
  return (seconds != 1) ? String.format(
      "%d seconds", seconds) : "1 second";
}
```

Then, how you might format the minute / minutes part -

```
static String formatTime(long millis) {
  long seconds = millis / 1000;
  if (seconds > 60) {
    long minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds -= (minutes * 60);
    if (minutes > 1) {
      return String.format("%d minutes, %s",
          minutes, formatSeconds(seconds));
    } else {
      return String.format("1 minute, %s",
          formatSeconds(seconds));
    }
  }
  return formatSeconds(seconds);
}
```

Finally, to tie it all together keep track of the System time when you start and calculate when you should end, then your current count down time is difference between the endtime and the current time - that is,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How much time (In Minutes) ?");
  int minutes = scan.nextInt();
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long endTime = startTime + (minutes * 60 * 1000);
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    System.out.println(formatTime(endTime
        - System.currentTimeMillis()));
  }
  System.out.println("Time's Up!");
}
```